# Warning - Conversion from size_t to DWORD, possible loss of data

Tags: c++, c-strings, fortify, strlen, dword

I'm building a 64bit C++ code on VS 2015.

```
DWORD blockLength;
blockLength = strlen((LPCSTR)sourceVar);    // sourceVar is of type Cstring, build warning here. 

// Allocate memory.
defaultBuffer = new unsigned char[blockLength + 1];

sprintf_s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(defaultBuffer), (blockLength + 1), "%s", (LPCSTR)sourceVar); 

// Decrypt data
if (!someMethod(someParameter, 0, 1, 0, defaultBuffer, &blockLength))
{
// Do something
}
```

When I run the code from HP-fortify, I don't see any build warnings or any fortify issues.

However, when I build the code separately, I see this **warning** on 2nd line -

```
warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data
```

Now, **when I make these code changes** -

```
blockLength = sourceVar.GetLength();
```

The build warning is gone. However, when I run this new code against **HP-Fortify**, I now see following error at sprintf_s line -

Buffer Overflow
(Input Validation and Representation, Data Flow)  - 
The function writes outside the bounds of allocated memory, which could corrupt data, cause the program to crash, or lead to the execution of malicious code.

Comment: You should add C++ tag. I doubt the question will get any attention otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning C4267 'argument': conversion from 'size\_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750207/warning-c4267-argument-conversion-from-size-t-to-dword-possible-loss-of)

Comment: The issue is that DWORD is 32bits in size, while size_t is probably 64bits.

Comment: You said elsewhere that if you used `inputString.GetLength()` you got an error in HP-Fortify, and that some later points required a `DWORD` instead of a `size_t`. You should add those details to the question.

Comment: "required a DWORD instead of a size_t"
This was for blockLength which is passed as a parameter to someMethod() mentioned above.

Comment: I would recommend against code like `(LPCSTR)sourceVar`.  If `sourceVar` happens to have a user-defined conversion operator to `LPCSTR` then the code will work; but if it doesn't then you get no compilation error and undefined behaviour at runtime.  You could use `static_cast<LPCSTR>(sourceVar)`, or preferably, directly invoke a method on `sourceVar` that returns the desired pointer.

Comment: @M.M I’m not a Windows C++ programmer so I’m not sure, but I *think* that `(LPCSTR)sourceVar` is the way Microsoft recommends. In any case, yes, `CString` does have that conversion operator.

Comment: @M.M: When I tried "sprintf_s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(defaultBuffer), (blockLength + 1), "%s", static_cast<LPCSTR>(sourceVar)); ", I'm still seeing the Fortify error. No build errors though.

Answer (score 2):

In 64-bit mode a size_t will be 64-bits, but a DWORD will always be 32-bit... 
So assigning a 64-bits value to 32 bits value looses the top 32-bits of the size_t, hence the warning.

Why you only get it in release mode - no idea.

Comment: "Why you only get it in release mode - no idea" - Didn't get your point.
will using 

    blockLength = int((LPCSTR)sourceVar); 

be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
blockLength = static_cast<int>(strlen((LPCSTR)sourceVar));
```

Using static_cast fixed the issue. There are no errors in HP Fortify and no warnings while building.